# React pass props down to all descendant Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children, descendant

The use case is I would like to "effortlessly" pass down a certain prop values to all descendant components. Not sure if this is even possible in React.

So instead of doing this:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super(props);
        this.props.componentID = "123456";
    }
    render() {
        return <Child1 componentID={this.props.componentID} />
    }
}

class Child1 extends Component {

    render() {
        return <Child2 componentID={this.props.componentID} />
    }
}

class Child2 extends Component {

    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.componentID}</div>
    }
}
```

Do something like this:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.props.componentID = "123456";
    }

    passComponentIDToAllDescendantComponents() {
        // Some super nifty code
    }

    render() {
        return <Child1 />
    }
}

// etc...
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: dont modify the props.. use setState

Comment: You should look at React's Context: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: @madox2 Thanks!!! Just what I was looking for

Comment: @madox2, Your comment should be marked as answer. I was about to write that this was not possible till I saw the React documentation. I felt passing props made sure that the code was readable.

Comment: Word of caution: make sure that there's a strong reason to pass the props this way down the tree in an invisible fashion (because your component jsx no more tells the full truth). Plus as of this writing, ReactJS docs say that this is an experimental feature, so it could change in the future in a way that can break your app.

Comment: Here's a nice summary on when to use and when not to use: http://reactkungfu.com/2016/01/react-context-feature-in-practice/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) feature to pass data down to the children. In your case it could look like this:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
    getChildContext() {
        return {componentID: "123456"};
    }
    render() {
        return <Child1 />
    }
}

Parent.childContextTypes = {
    componentID: React.PropTypes.string
};

class Child1 extends Component {

    render() {
        return <Child2 />
    }
}

class Child2 extends Component {

    render() {
        return <div>{this.context.componentID}</div>
    }
}

Child2.contextTypes = {
    componentID: React.PropTypes.string
};
```